# How can I hook up an old cast iron hot water heater to my hydronic heating system

Tags: hydronic, galvanic-corrosion

The existing hydronic system is run in copper with finned tubing in baseboard heating mostly.  We split off a chunk of bedroom to make a small ensuite.  It currently has a a 1KW electric heater.  I have a cast iron radiator that I'd like to put in the bathroom both for room heat and as a towel warmer.

I need to connect the iron eventually the copper manifold.  Would this be best done with PEX and a plastic bushing?  I am concerned about galvanic action between the copper and the iron.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, in that you cannot connect dissimilar metals (copper and iron) directly without incurring galvanic corrosion.  A nonconductive interface is required.  PEX would be fine, as would CPVC, as long temp is under 200F.  Couplers to copper and iron are available for both.  PVC would NOT handle hot water.

Comment: Ooo! Thanks for the reminder about PVC vs CPVC.  Now I I need to find out what material my bushings are.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Don't forget to come back and let us know if this answered your question, or if you have a follow-up.  Good luck!